# как передать значения во views.py Django, которые я хочу получить в input форме HTML для последующего сравнения?

Tags: html, django, input

есть view Django:

```
class Filters(Category, ListView):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_q = Q()
        if 'category' in self.request.GET:
            my_q = Q(category__in=self.request.GET.getlist('category'))
        if 'temp_sveta' in self.request.GET:
            my_q &= Q(temp_sveta__in=self.request.GET.getlist('temp_sveta'))
        if 'protection' in self.request.GET:
            my_q &= Q(protection__in=self.request.GET.getlist('protection'))
        
        queryset = Catalog.objects.filter(my_q)
        return queryset
```

как правильно передать сюда значения, которые я хочу получить в input форме HTML

```
<input type="number" name="min_power">
```

чтобы потом сравнить значение с БД?

Answer (score 0):

ответ оказался лишь в привидении типов

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    min_power = self.request.GET.get('min_power')

    my_q = Q()
    if 'category' in self.request.GET:
        my_q = Q(category__in=self.request.GET.getlist('category'))
    if min_power:
        my_q &= Q(power__gte=int(min_power))
```